# Building WebApps with Azure AD for Business in Python

Tags: python, azure, flask, jinja2

I'm relatively new to programming and I'm trying to build a Flask WebApp that shows information depending on which Azure Active Directory group you belong to.
For example,
If the groups were:
Group A and Group B,
upon signing in, people in group A should be able to only see the information set for their group.
I used Azure portal's sample code in Python to set up the authentication, yet I don't know how to call on their information rather than their name.
In HTML with JINJA, the code looks like this:

```
<h1>Welcome {{user.get("name")}} </h1>
```

Since I am using Microsoft Authentication, I don't know what other information I can access other than the name (since it was in the sample). I only really need the group and I would really appreciate any help I can get.

Comment: The information you can access is limited by the permissions consented to with your app registration (some permissions require a Global Admin to consent to). Microsoft Graph is their REST API to access/interact with user/group/site etc information. [Group API Info](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/groups-overview?view=graph-rest-1.0)

Comment: You can refer to [Integrating B2C feature of Microsoft identity platform with a Python web application](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-python-webapp/blob/master/README_B2C.md), [graph.microsoft getting Groups](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-python-webapp/issues/62) and [Using AAD Group](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-python-webapp/issues/23)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Here is the [Document](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-python-webapp/blob/master/README_B2C.md) which gives you related discussions about Building Azure AD using Python.
- Below are the steps to configure the sample.

1. Cone or Download this repository

```html
git clone https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-python-webapp.git
```

2. Install Sample dependency
3. Configure the sample to use your Azure AD B2C

- You can even check these documents with related discussions.
  [Using AAD Group · Issue #23 · Azure-Samples/ms-identity-python-webapp · GitHub](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-python-webapp/issues/23)